# using omniauth how to change callback path dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I want to change omniauth callback url dynamically.
but I don't know how to change dynamically.

I hope change when put path on view, not config loaded.

like this

```
- if @is_android
  - callback_path = omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, "facebook",   callback_path: "/resource/auth/facebook/callback/android")
- else
  - callback_path = omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, "facebook")

= link_to "sign up with facebook", fb_auth_path
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems, like this is not possible. `omniauth` gem works as a Rack middleware, therefore it must be loaded on startup.

The `omniauth_authorize_path` is basically useless. It only is there, so that you can create paths nicely in a Rails way and you don't have to write `link_to 'FB', '/auth/facebook'`.

So my best advice it to distinguish the two actions easily in the controller, like I did in my app:

```rb
def facebook
  if user_signed_in?
    bind_facebook_account
  else
    login_or_preregister
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your comment,but i didnt understand mean...
i tried to hook omniauth_authrize_path and change request for facebook.
like this

 `
  class MyApp::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    if user_signed_in?
      bind_facebook_account
    else
      login_or_preregister
    end
  end
 `

but i cant hook /auth/facebook, so i cant anything request_phase.

Comment: If you run `rake routes`, you should see the omniauth routes. If not, follow [this example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview) in devise Wiki. Anyway, as I can remember, devise uses the "users" prefix for the path. Than it should be `/users/auth/facebook`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [route constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) in order to decide which route to use as a callback.

Basically the constraint return true or false, having the `request` as a parameter, so you might do something like:

```
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#android_new", :constraints => IsAndroidConstraint
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#new"
```